# ES6 root consts inaccessible from function

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an app using es2015. Ideally we'd like to just write es2015 code and run that code on the browser, since we are targeting browsers with es2015 support. However, I have a problem with the following code in Safari 10.1:

```
const rootX = 1;
var varX = 2;

function g(){
  console.log('var inside : ', varX);
  console.log('const inside : ', rootX);
}
g();
```

In Safari 10.1, I get "Reference error, can't find variable: rootX" on the second console output line. Is this the correct ES6 behavior? I can't seem to find anyone talking about this scenario on the web. My guess is that the function is being hoisted above the `const` definition and therefore the `const` is undefined. The same code works in Chrome.

The only workaround I can find is to make `g` a fat-arrow function. I would be OK with this except it seems that some npm modules we use run afoul of this issue as well. Is this the expected behavior for es2015? Can I expect that library writers will fix these issues in the future, or is there something I can do to mitigate this now?

You can try it out here:
http://jsbin.com/taruwudufu/edit?html,js,output

UPDATE: Safari Technology Preview doesn't throw this error, so it looks like it's indeed a Safari bug and will be fixed going forward.

Comment: No, that’s not correct ES6 behaviour. It doesn’t really make sense that changing `g` to an arrow function would fix anything, either.

Comment: `Can I expect that library writers will fix these issues in the future` - if that code behaves as you say, then the problem is with Safari's javascript engine - Safari, the new Internet Exploder

Comment: Yeah I've run into this before too. Absolutely a Safari bug around block scoping.

Comment: Does going into strict mode help?

Comment: @Ryan strict mode does not help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that actually runs in the JSBin runner:

```
try {
    const rootX = 1;
    var varX = 2;

    function g() {
        window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log('var inside : ', varX);
        window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log('const inside : ', rootX);
    }
    g();
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

What I can see could be happening here is:

1. `rootX` is scoped to the try block
2. `varX` and `g()` are hoisted and scoped to the global scope

When `g()` executes `varX` is available via the global scope. `rootX` however is not declared on the global scope and a `ReferenceError` is thrown.

Note: Simply running the code snippet in Safari's js console works fine. And, running the code snippet with a surrounding try-catch statement throws a `ReferenceError` for `rootX`.

Note 2: If the global scope is not used the code runs in Safari.

```js
(function() {
    const rootX = 1;
    var varX = 2;

    function g() {
        console.log('var inside : ', varX);
        console.log('const inside : ', rootX);
    }
    g();
})();
```

A work-around might be to wrap build output files in an IIFE.

Comment: I think the console result might be a red herring, since each line is evaluated as it's entered if not inside a block. I originally encountered this problem inside an ES6 module.

Comment: Might be. I added another note in case it helps.